# Why are these resources failing to load?

Tags: asp.net, css, png, http-status-code-404, google-chrome-devtools

My asp.net project has several .png (and a few .gif) files in the \Content\Images folder.

Two are not found; Chrome Dev Tool's Console tells me: "*Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)*"

...and sure enough, if I click the links that it shows (e.g., *http://localhost/@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[%22ThisApp%22]/Content/Images/PlatypusorangeSprite.png*) it takes me to GDT's Resources tab, and although the Images folder shows that file as being there, but there is a "broken image" representation of it.

The same thing happens with just one other image file (they are all in the same location, and the references to them, in CSS file declarations, is indeed pointing to where they exist, such as:

```
background:#E5EDFE url('/@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ThisApp"]/Content/Images/PlatypusorangeSprite.png') repeat-x 0 -369px;
```

I can 2-click those files in the VS2010 IDE, and they open up and seem to look fine.

So why are they not being found at browsetime/seen as broken images?

### UPDATE

Well, apparently it's got someting to do with my moving all the style declarations out of the cshtml file into a separate stylesheet/CSS file that is referenced in the page (I went back to the bad old way and it works fine - the pngs are found again (I even imagined that I heard them singing "*Amazing Grace*")). Since it is not a relative path to those pngs, why would it matter that the style info is in a .css file in the Content folder as opposed to being "inline"?

I hate it when you do the "right" thing and it makes things worse.

Comment: Are other png and gifs loading? Unsure from your question, if all if them fail to load I would check mime types are set on the server.

Comment: I mention that only two do not load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Some clients accidentally transform suffixes to big letters like .JPG or .PNG. If you call them by .jpg or .png, it will not match.
2. Render your template by compiling in Visual Studio, open your browser, look into your HTML and check the rendered path of your image:`<image src="..." />`. Alternatively, try to call the image direcly via ftp by url in browser like ftp://www.mysite/pics/ for example and click on link, that shows the image. Then you get the correct path in the url.
3. Also check if the suffix ist accidentally doubled like mypic.jpg.jpg.

Comment: Then why is there no problem with the others? I'll try it, though, just for grins...what's it going to hurt - not find it a second time?

Answer (score 1):

Any case sensitivity discrepancies,perhaps?

Comment: No, the actual file name is PlatypusorangeSprite.png and that is how it is referenced...

Comment: Ahh. so that is because the images are being referenced now from where the stylesheet is located. and not your html file. So.. if you have your css file down in another directory, say, css/layout.css, then your image references have to come out of the css folder, ../

Comment: You're probably right (empirical observation would suggest that), but it seems to me that the reference is an explicit full path so that it should not matter where the reference is made from...

Comment: Hmmm.. yeah, you are right. Absolute url reference would have no impact. I'm stumped on that one then. If you keep digging into it, keep me posted.